# data recovery - accidentally started startup-disc creation on wrong disk

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

I wanted to create an Ubuntu startup disk using starup-sik-creator, but accidentally I selected the wrong disk. I stopped the process at about 16%, but the data is lost, is there a way to restore even if some data is destroyed, I would like to recover as much as possible.

Tank you.